# Detect slope in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making 2D game in `Unity` and I want to detect when player is grounded on slope.
I'm using this code for slope detection but this code work ONLY when player is facing(moving) down to the slope. When player is moving up to the slope this code return `false`.

```
private bool OnSlope()
{
    if (isJumping)
        return false;

    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(groundCheck.position, Vector2.down, 0.5f, whatIsGround);

    if (hit.collider)
        if (hit.normal != Vector2.up)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Can someone tell me how to modify this code to work wen player is moving up and down to the slope

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if (hit.collider)
    return true
return false
```

I believe the collider won't exist if the raycast doesn't intersect with ground.

Answer (score 0):

Does your player change their forward direction when they turn around?
If so you can take the dot product of the player's forward direction with the slope normal.
If the product is positive then the player's forward direction is generally inline with the slope direction - so they are facing downhill, if the product is negative then the vectors are generally facing away from each other so the player is facing uphill.

```
if(Mathf.sign(Vector2.Dot(transform.forward,hit.normal) == 1){
    // facing downhill
else{
    // facing uphill
}
```

If you don't change your forward vector when you turn around you can always store your own based on the last inputed direction.
Hope this helps